# Importing skins in Android Studio (Galaxy Note 4)

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-galaxy, virtual-device-manager

I downloaded a copy of Android Studio and also some of the skins for Galaxy devices (Note 3, Note 4, Note 5, Tab 10 7") and wanted to import the skins into the Virtual Device Configuration screens. I see the 'Import Hardware Profiles' buttons and point it toward the folder with the skin (hardware.ini file) but it never seems to import anything or add the skin I am trying to import to the list anywhere. Am I missing something, doing something wrong or is this broken at the moment? Can anyone tell me how I import the Samsung skins into Android Studio's virtual device manager?

Comment: FYI, I also tried copying the skin into the android SDK platforms/skins folder and it doesn't show up then either.

Answer (score 23):

Here is how I go about it...

1) Download the skin set, hardware.ini, and other necessary files; usually found as a zipped file containing everything you and AVDM needs

2) Since it usually comes in a zipped file, extract files

3) Place the folder containing the extracted files into your specified place. I use: C:/programs/android for my own convenience and logic.

NOTE: References from Developer.Android.com and Samsung recommend to house them in the "Android SDK > Platforms > android-## > skins" folder. I have found you can just put it anywhere, for convenience, with no issues. But you can certainly put it in the skins folder, if you prefer. Again, I use the first Android folder in the Programs folder in my C drive.

4) Launch Android Studio

5) Launch the Android Virtual Device Manager

6) Click on Create Virtual Device

7) Click on New Hardware Profile

8) Fill out completely, but without pointing to the skin, leave that blank

9) Click Finish

10) Highlight your newly created Hardware Profile, and click the Edit button

11) Click the ... button next to skins to browser your system

NOTE: This is why I don't go putting the skins in the recommended platforms skins folder because the browse option gives me more control over file location and organization.

12) Locate your skin folder and highlight the folder, do not go into the folder, just highlight the folder

13) Click OK

14) If any warning appear make sure you are at the correct directory for your 
skin, it may be in a nested folder

15) Click Finish

16) Highlight the Hardware you created, which now has your skin applied

17) Click Next

18) Fill out accordingly for your devices needs

19) Click Finish

20) Now at the Android Virtual Device Manager, Launch your newly created Device

21) Enjoy the Skin you Applied!!!

Good Luck and Enjoy!

Comment: Why are we not setting the skin on step 8?

Comment: It has been awhile since I've had to apply a skin But what I remember was it caused an issue of some sort with the directory path and nested folders while navigating to it at step 11 and 12 was more stable. At least for that version of Android Studio as things may have changed since then.

Comment: Actually this creates a new emulator just fine, but the skin is not showing on the emulator. The buttons seem to be the same still. Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: NOTE: After following the steps, my skin wasn't showing up when I launched the emulator. I quit both the emulator and Android Studio, then relaunched them. My skin showed up after that. I'm on a Mac.